# Understanding もう少しゆっくり休む - "Take the day off more slowly"?

Tags: translation

I have a long translation I need to do. It has basically talked about how the speaker's younger brother was very sick. The last sentence of the translation is the following.

> 弟が、明日、会社に行けるかわかりませんが、
>   できたら
>   **もう少しゆっくり**休んでもらいたいと思います。

Here is what I have so far.

> I do not know whether my younger brother will be able to go to the company tomorrow but
>   if he can
>   I think I want to receive his action of taking the day off **a little more slowly**

That last line doesn't sound right to me. "Taking the day off a little more slowly". Can anyone think of a better translation?

Comment: There is something that has been bugging me about the Japanese sentences that you have been posting here and that is the over-use of commas.  Today is no exception.  The first two commas are completely useless and highly unnatural if I may be honest.

Comment: It's my professor who writes the sentences (and he is Japanese). Maybe it's an age thing? I think he's in his 40s/50s or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know if my brother will be able to go to work tomorrow,
>  but if possible
>  I would like him to rest(ゆっくり休む) a little longer(もう少し).

The もう少し doesn't refer to him resting "more slowly", it's resting for a longer period of time.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the function of ゆっくり in this scenario then.

Comment: http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%82%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8A%E4%BC%91
ゆっくり commonly comes with 休む. It doesn't have to be there but it emphasises "taking it easy", "being at rest".

Answer (score 5):

It's true that ゆっくり means "slowly", but it can also mean leisurely (like のんびり) or being at comfort or at ease (like 楽に). If you go to a restaurant in Japan, you'll often hear ゆっくりどうぞ, which doesn't mean "Eat slowly", but rather "Take your time".

So when paired with 休む, ゆっくり indicates taking the time necessary to be comfortable.

Edit: And like Ash said, it's very common to hear ゆっくり used in conjunction with 休む.

Comment: @RachelG. Think about when you relax.  How fast are you moving?  Pretty slowly eh? ;).  That's the kind of feeling that I get from it.